# building an extension: how can I create a multiple-step form?

Tags: extension, php

If I just had .php files I would do the following:
`step1.php`'s submit button goes to `step2.php`. `step2.php`'s submit button goes to `step3.php`, etc.

The problem is that I need data that the user entered in step1 in order to display step2. For step3 I need data from step2, etc.

I tried creating multiple forms with `civix generate:form`, but how can I get data entered in previous steps?

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways to handle this.

Before proceeding down this path, consider if Webform-CiviCRM integration (for Drupal) or Caldera Forms-CiviCRM integration (for WordPress) will work for you - it will save you a lot of work if so.

If that's NOT an option, consider a) storing the data in the database (using the `postProcess` hook), b) storing the data in the `$_SESSION` variable, or c) using jQuery to fake having a multi-page form on a single page.

Comment: None of these seem to be really elegant. Is there no better way? I saw this kind of pattern (chained forms with "next" buttons) quite often in CiviCRM, and thought there was a "default" way of doing this. Thanks a lot for your answer anyway!

Comment: Can you give an example of such a form?  Most examples I can think of (e.g. contribution page workflow) store data in the db.  If you did this outside Civi, how would you store the data between forms?

Comment: Option b) with the `$_SESSION` variable seems to be a nice and easy workaround. Do you have an idea of how I can achieve that the next form (e.g `step2`) is displayed after `step1` has postprocessed its input?

Comment: See here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=31729.0

Comment: thanks for the link! And sorry, I did not see your other comment before submitting mine. A example would be in CiviRule, where there is a "next" button that leads to another form which allows to further specify the rule. Outside of civi I would not exactly store the data, but just pass it on to the next form. (using the `$_POST` - Variable)

Comment: For what its worth I used jQuery to 'fake' the multi-page form and it worked well for me. I've also used Webform CiviCRM for Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to using AngularJS, I think you could use the [crmUiWizard](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0b1991948184b8d6b4e290f8514406f7fd620c21/ang/crmUi.js#L750-L750) directive, which is how CiviMail seems to create a multi-step form for building mailings.